# Calling a Webservice with ASP.NET AJAX Clientside-only Script from a ASP.NET MVC App?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-ajax

i am looking for a basic example that shows how i could call a webservice with the client side javascript that comes with the ASP.NET Ajax Toolkit.

i already found some example that shows how you do it with ASP.NET WebForms but i am using ASP.NET MVC so no fancy ScriptManager for me :(

does somebody know a insightful blog posting about this topic?

tia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this post](http://www.techtribe.com/viewBlogEntry.html?blogEntryId=693a3f1a-47bd-102b-9fc2-000f1f68a9bf) for a description of how this can be accomplished using AJAX for ASP.NET MVC.

If you have control of the service your self and if it is possible you could consider exposing it as a REST-like interface via WebHttpBinding and WCF. Then use jQuery to query the service.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using JQuery and this guide is very straightforward for calling an ASP.NET Web Service:

http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this can help you?

1. [Using jQuery with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.chadmyers.com/Blog/archive/2007/12/13/using-jquery-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx)
2. [AJAX Panels with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/AJAX_Panels_with_ASPNET_MVC.aspx)
3. [Adding Ajax Support to the ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/12/ajax-aspnet-mvc)